# Excel interop and .net 4 book suggestion

Tags: c#, .net, interop, excel-2007

I need to gain some knowledge in the excel interop line. I have looked at some of the tutorials online,
they teach the very basics like opening a workbook. I would appreciate any help suggestions for books in that line.

I am supposed to use .net 4.0 , excel 2007 and c#.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the introduction of dynamic and DLR in .NET 4.0 interop with COM components like excel has become much much simpler!!

```
Type excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
excel.Visible = true;
excel.Workbooks.Add();
```

With this simple code you can work on excel. I am not sure about specific books targeting COM components interop with .NET 4.0, but some of the books that have sections providing good explanations on them:

1. Programming C# 4.0: Building Windows, Web, and RIA Applications for the .NET 4.0 Framework by O'Reilly - See chapter 17
2. Introducing .Net 4.0: With Visual Studio 2010 By Alex Mackey - See Chapter 3
3. C# 4.0 Unleashed By Bart De Smet - See chapter 22

In all these books, they have explained how to make the best use of .NET 4.0 for Interop with Office components like word, excel.

Hope this will help u a little

Comment: I was hoping a more specific book would be available , i decided to go with C# 4.0 unleashed as i found it at a nearby library.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Books on VSTO](http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/02/10/books-on-vsto/) - it has a pretty large list of books.